# javascript mootools smooth scroll by 'x' amount of pixels

Tags: javascript, mootools

I am trying to smooth scroll down 180px using javascript/mootools.

I have the following js code:

```
document.documentElement.scrollTop = document.documentElement.scrollTop + 180;
```

But how can I for instance make this work over a course of 500ms so it animates the scroll rather than it jumping down (which it does at present).

Cheers,
Adi

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can by using [Fx.SmoothScroll](http://mootools.net/docs/more/Fx/Fx.SmoothScroll)

```
var ss = new Fx.SmoothScroll({duration: 500 /* ms */}, window);

$('scroll').addEvent('click', function(){ ss.start(0, 180 /* Y offset of the window */); });
```

​demo: http://jsfiddle.net/TmBkj/1/

**edit**: remember to include the plugin (not by default on the core) or include the more bundle

Comment: that works always from the top but what if i wanted it to scroll 180px down no matter where you are on the page? Imagine your scroll element in your fiddle has css position:fixed

Comment: actually, think i have it

var ss = new Fx.SmoothScroll({duration: 500 /* ms */}, window);
$('scroll').addEvent('click', function(){
var foo = document.body.scrollTop;
    ss.start(foo,foo+180 /* Y offset of the window */); });

Comment: yours (like mine) seems to jump to top for a fraction of a second before it scrolls down 180. Any idea why? maybe just jsfiddle issue, havent tried in basic html page.

Comment: Yeah I've noticed it aswell.. could be a jsfiddle issue but also a mootools bug.. I ll report it to the core devs :)

Comment: I'll let you know how it goes tomorrow (whether its a mootools or fiddle issue)

Comment: I had some issues with smoothscroll setting #undefined so this worked best. new Fx.Scroll(window).start(window.getScroll().y, window.getScroll().y + 180);