# smooth scroll by x pixels using arrow keys up and down

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to make the whole html page smooth scrolling by hitting arrow keys up and down by exact amount of pixels. (EXAMPLE: I hit arrow down and the page scrolls down by 300px then I hit that arrow again and it scrolls again by 300px, then I hit up arrow key and it scrolls up by 300px...) I founded these posts: [similiar post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14156663/jquery-smoothdivscroll-and-arrow-keys) [similiar post 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12316164/javascript-mootools-smooth-scroll-by-x-amount-of-pixels)but I dont know how to make the arrow keys working with it. Can you please help me?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know whether it helps you or not..but a suggestion to go through with this(jscrollpane.kelvinluck.com) [site](http://jscrollpane.kelvinluck.com/) for the scroll, I have modified my web pages to have simple scrolls with the help of this..